# type myEventHandler<T extends myEvent> = (event: T) => void;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to typescript.

Wondering what exactly this line means in TS?:

```
type myEventHandler<T extends myEvent> = (event: T) => void;
```

I know that <> is a type assertion. So I guess myEventHandler should be the type of T.
But the 'myEventHandler' is also a type, right? So is that mean we can define a type that belongs to another type?? I guess the event:T is a parameter, so a type can also have a parameter? This line looks like a fat arrow function... and it has a void. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

In this case `<T extends myEvent>` is **not** a type assertion. It rather declares the type as [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). You can now pass arguments of **any** type `T`, as long as the type `extends myEvent`.

You should read the [TypeScript introduction to Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) for further reference.

Comment: Finish read the link. Still not sure about this line. So the <T extends myEvent> is a type variable that generic over the type myEventHandler? Or the type myEventHandler is a generic type? or both of them are generic type?